# Galaxy S2 turns off randomly

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, power-on, troubleshooting

I got a problem with my Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100.
I have it for round about 8 monthts now and experimented with some custom roms. I installed cynogenmod 9, 10, 10.1 tested Syah Kernel and installed AOKP in DualBoot and so on. 
Everything was fine until I installed CM10.1 as single boot. 
 
There my phone started to turn off randomly and I thought that it would be a software mistake and reinstalled the Samsung stock rom. But the problem is still existing. 
 
I dont use a firewall or antivirus program and did not checked up anything. 
 
Can you help me with this issue or tell me how I should start detecting or solving the problem? 
 
Thanks for your help!

 
Edit: 
I installed awg Antivirus and scanned my phone. Beside SWFPlayer there was no app which is "dangerous". And my "marked" settings were "Enable Debugging", "Allow Third Party Apps".

Edit 2: 
I now updated my phone via Kies to Android 4.1.2 but the problem still exists.

 
Edit 3: 
I think I got the problem. I already wrote it in my last comment. The batterie infalted and I think  that's the problem. I ordered a new batterie and hope that's it. If not I don't know what it might be...

Comment: See [our chat protocol](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8311004#8311004) -- it's not your phone, but CM10.1

Comment: I do not use CM 10.1 anymore. I reinstalled newest stock rom from Samsung.

Comment: Just to clearify: The problem *started* with CM10.1, but even *persisted* after you flashed to stock?

Comment: Yes thtat is correct!

Comment: Do you still use the dual boot kernel after flashing a stock rom? Try flashing the stock kernel also and check if it helps

Comment: When I flashed the stock rom I entered a recovery differing from the Siyah Recovery. So I think it is not installed anymore. But beside starting the recovery, I checked my Android information with one of my mates who never flashe dhis phone and the information are equal.

Comment: Do you use a battery saver app?  I have found that they cause random reboots and/or sleep of death with my GS2.

Comment: No I don't use something like that. Only AdAways, Firewall, AntiVir.

Comment: After I started the adb Logcat to find the reason for the shutdowns (and I did not find any) I removed the batterie. And than I noticed that it has inflated. So I think it is the batteire which is not working.